# ¿Como hacer de un div que está en el cuerpo de una pagina un menú lateral de hamburguesa?

Tags: php, html, css

Buenas comunidad, mi problema radica básicamente en que necesito que mi div cuando empiece a poner la pagina en vista mobile se coloque como un menú y no se como llevar eso a mi maquetado, si alguien tiene un ejemplo de verdad se los agradecería mucho

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <!-- <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
  <title>Ayuda</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.drawer.css"> -->
  <link href="css/style1.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
</head>
<body style="background: #d3d3d3">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <?php
    require 'header1.php';
    ?>
  </div>

  <!--star left side-->
  <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 padre-contenido">
    <div class="padre_article">
      <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 box-right" id="prinarticle">
      </div> <!--end of the left side -->

      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 calendar"> <!-- rigth side ESTE ES EL DIV QUE QUIERO CONVERTIR EN UN MENÚ LATERAL DE HAMBURGUESA -->
        <div class="">
          <div class="asedi text-center box-right">
            <h1 class=" color-white text-NL text-45 decora-title">CALENDAR</h1>
            <div id="datetimepickr12" class="calendario"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="asedi text-center box-right">
            <h1 class="color-white text-NL text-45 decora-title">TITLE 1</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="asedi text-center box-right">
            <h1 class="color-white text-NL text-45 decora-title">TITLE 2</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="asedi text-center box-right">
            <h1 class="color-white text-NL text-45 decora-title">TITLE 3</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
     </div><!--end rigth side HASTA ACA -->
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 bottomBoxes"> <!-- bottom boxes -->
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 marginArticlesBox">
      <div class="articlesBottom text-center " >
        <h1 class="text-NL text-32 color-2 ">CONTENT TITLE</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 marginArticlesBox">
      <div class="articlesBottom text-center" >
        <h1 class="text-NL text-32 color-2">CONTENT TITLE</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 marginArticlesBox">
      <div class="articlesBottom text-center ">
        <h1 class="text-NL text-32 color-2">CONTENT TITLE</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
 </div><!--end bottom boxes-->

 <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 linksother"> <!-- sharing links -->
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-5 col-xs-5 text-center tapeLetter">
      OTHER SHARING LINK
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-5 col-xs-5 text-center tapeLetter">
      OTHER SHARING LINK
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-5 col-xs-5 text-center tapeLetter">
      OTHER SHARING LINK
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-5 col-xs-5 text-center tapeLetter" >
      OTHER SHARING LINK
    </div>
</div><!-- end sharing links -->

  <footer class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 footerContainer">
    <?php
    require 'footer1.php';
    ?>
  </footer>
</div>
</body>

<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/functions.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- <script src="js/drawer.js"></script> -->
</body>
</html>
```

si falta algo en el código háganme saber para colocarlo. Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

Prueba esto, toda la funcionalidad es posible con css solo sin utilizar jQuery.

```js
// se guarda la referencia del icono en una varibale.
var icon = $('#menu');
        var list$ = $('.list');

        icon.click(function () {
            list$.toggleClass('make-visible');
            list$.toggleClass('list');
        });

        // el evento resize hace que elimine la clase make-visible en caso de que esté activada. 
        $(window).resize(function (param) {
            if ($(this).width() >= 700) {
                list$.removeClass('make-visible');
                list$.addClass('list');
            }
        });
```

```css
 * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        nav {
            display: block;
            color: white;
            display: flex;
            flex-flow: row wrap;
            background-color: darkmagenta;
        }

        .icon-container {
            flex: 0.5 1 10%;
        }

        #menu {
            font-size: 2em;
            padding: 0.5em;
            visibility: hidden;
            cursor: pointer;
            text-decoration: none;
            color: white;
        }

        nav ul {
            flex: 1 0 80%;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: flex-end;
            flex-flow: row wrap;
            list-style: none;
        }

        ul li {
            padding: 1em;
            flex: 0 0 10%;
            cursor: pointer;
            text-align: center;
        }

        ul li:hover {
            background-color: brown;
        }

        .make-visible {
            display: block;
        }

        @media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
            nav {
                flex-flow: column wrap;
            }
            #menu {
                visibility: visible;
            }
            .list {
                display: none;
            }
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
        <nav>
            <div class="icon-container">
                <a href="#" id="menu">&#8801;</a>
            </div>
            <ul class="list">
                <li>Item 1</li>
                <li>Item 2</li>
                <li>Item 3</li>
                <li>Item 4</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

Comment: _toda la funcionalidad es posible con css solo sin utilizar jQuery_ En tu ejemplo estás usando JQuery, creo que deberías mostrar un ejemplo sin usar JQuery ya que lo indicas en tu respuesta.

Comment: He hecho el ejemplo con jQuery porque vi que lo utilizabas.

Comment: Si uso Jquery, pedía un ejemplo para ver si puedo adaptar a lo que necesito que es realizar ese menú pero no con el header, si no con un div del cuerpo, de hecho lo indiqué en el código HTML que puse, muchas gracias por la ayuda, veré si puedo hacer lo que les digo y pondré la respuesta en tal caso